# Trying to recursively loop the folder contents

Tags: c, file, recursion, directory, count

I'm trying to create a function which recursively returns the contents of a folder. While testing it, I encounter some problems. With some folders it works, With others it gives me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS, and sometimes it just stops.

I have been trying to debug it with GDB for a long time, but I just can't find a solution to my problem. The function is not quit short an goes as follows.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>

/* THIS IS AN EXTRACT FROM A LARGER FILE
 THERE MAY BE TO MUCH INCLUDE STATEMENTS
 */

struct Directory {
    DIR *handle;
    const char *filename;
};
typedef struct Directory Directory;

int DirectoryCreate(const char *n, Directory *d) {
    DIR *dh;
    char *str;

    dh = opendir(n);
    if(dh == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    d->handle = dh;
    str = malloc(strlen(n) + 1);
    if(str == NULL) {
        errno = ENOMEM;
        closedir(d->handle);
        return -1;
    }
    strcpy(str, n);
    d->filename = (const char *)str;
    return 0;
}

void DirectoryFree(Directory *s) {
    if(s->handle) {
        closedir(s->handle);
    }
    if(s->filename) {
        free((void *)s->filename);
    }
}

void FreeDirectoryArray(Directory *array, size_t size) {
    register size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        DirectoryFree(&(array[i]));
    }

    free(array);
}

Directory *ReadFolders = NULL;
size_t ReadFoldersSize = 0;
const char *ReadFolderFilename = NULL;
const char *ReadNextRecursiveItemInFolder(const char *folder) {
    struct dirent *entry;
    struct stat fileStatus;
    int status;
    mode_t mode;
    const char *newFilename;
    char *fullName;
    char *ptr;
    size_t strLen;

    if(folder == NULL && ReadFolders == NULL) {
        errno = 0;
        return NULL;
    }

    if(folder != NULL) {
        /* free the previous directory list */
        FreeDirectoryArray(ReadFolders, ReadFoldersSize);
        ReadFolders = NULL;
        ReadFoldersSize = 0;

        /* open the new directory */
        ReadFolders = (Directory *)realloc(ReadFolders, sizeof(Directory));
        ReadFoldersSize++;
        status = DirectoryCreate(folder, ReadFolders);
        if(status != 0) {
            FreeDirectoryArray(ReadFolders, ReadFoldersSize-1);
            ReadFolders = NULL;
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    entry = readdir(ReadFolders[ReadFoldersSize - 1].handle);
    /* If NULL, go to previous folder */
    if(entry == NULL) {
        DirectoryFree(&(ReadFolders[ReadFoldersSize - 1]));
        --ReadFoldersSize;

        /* if it's empty, we've reached the end */
        if(ReadFoldersSize == 0) {
            free(ReadFolders);
            ReadFolders = NULL;
            errno = 0;
            return NULL;
        }

        newFilename = ReadNextRecursiveItemInFolder(NULL);
        return newFilename;
    }
    /* Make sure the entry name is not . or .. */
    if(strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0) {
        newFilename = ReadNextRecursiveItemInFolder(NULL);
        return newFilename;
    }

    /* we've got an entry, now construct the full path */
    strLen = 
        strlen(ReadFolders[ReadFoldersSize - 1].filename) +
        1 +
        strlen(entry->d_name);
    fullName = malloc(strLen + 1);
    ptr = fullName;
    strcpy(ptr, ReadFolders[ReadFoldersSize - 1].filename);
    ptr += strlen(ReadFolders[ReadFoldersSize - 1].filename);
    strcpy(ptr, "/");
    ptr++;
    strcpy(ptr, entry->d_name);
    newFilename = fullName;

    /* no recurse on symbolic links */
    status = lstat(newFilename, &fileStatus);
    if(status != 0) {
        FreeDirectoryArray(ReadFolders, ReadFoldersSize);
        ReadFolders = NULL;
        ReadFoldersSize = 0;
        return NULL;
    }

    mode = fileStatus.st_mode;
    /* if not readable for file or not searchable for folder, get next */
    /* if folder and not link, recursively continue */
    /* else  return the new name */
    if((((mode & S_IFDIR) == S_IFDIR) && (mode & S_IXUSR) != S_IXUSR) || 
        (mode & S_IRUSR) != S_IRUSR) {
        free((void *)newFilename);
        newFilename = ReadNextRecursiveItemInFolder(NULL);
        return newFilename;

    } else if((mode & S_IFDIR) && (mode & S_IFLNK) != S_IFLNK) {
        ReadFolders = realloc(ReadFolders, ReadFoldersSize + 1);
        ReadFoldersSize++;
        errno = 0;
        status = DirectoryCreate(newFilename, &(ReadFolders[ReadFoldersSize - 1]));
        if(status != 0) {
            FreeDirectoryArray(ReadFolders, ReadFoldersSize - 1);
            ReadFolders = NULL;
            ReadFoldersSize = 0;
            return NULL;
        }

        if(newFilename != ReadFolderFilename) {
            free((void *)ReadFolderFilename);
            ReadFolderFilename = newFilename;
        }

    } else {
        if(newFilename != ReadFolderFilename) {
            free((void *)ReadFolderFilename);
            ReadFolderFilename = newFilename;
        }
        errno = 0;
    }

    return ReadFolderFilename;
}

int main() {
    const char *filename = "/Users/";
    const char *entry;

    while(1) {
        entry = ReadNextRecursiveItemInFolder(filename);
        filename = NULL;
        if(entry == NULL) {
            if(errno == 0) {
                printf("End reached\n");
            } else {
                printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            }
            break;
        }

        printf("Entry: %s\n", entry);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'll give a brief explanation how the code works. To start looping a directory, you have to give the full directory path to the function. All subsequent calls have to pass NULL to get the next item in line, unless they want to process another directory.

The code counts every file and folder in a folder, recursively. It does not follow symbolic links, and it only counts readable files and executable directories. To keep track of its 'flow', the function uses 3 global variables:

- `ReadFolders`: an array of `Directory` structures used to keep track of different levels of folders. The last one at the back.
- `ReadFoldersSize`: the amount of `Directory` structures in ReadFolders.
- `ReadFolderFilename`: the string that contains the last item processed.

I hope I can find some help around here,
ief2.

Comment: Do you develop app for iPhone and getting  this exception ?

Comment: Not at all, I develop it for use in Mac OS X and Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The realloc size is wrong : it not "n" but "n*size".

So the line 153 should be :

```
ReadFolders = realloc(ReadFolders, (ReadFoldersSize + 1)*sizeof(Directory));
```